# I can not start mxnet R for GPU in windows 10

Tags: r, installation, windows-10, gpu, mxnet

Hi I try to install mxnet R in windows.
Followed by mxnet.com web page, https://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/get_started/install.html,
I ran the prebuild package. The command looks to be run successfully. But when I start mxnet by "library(mxnet)", I see the following error.

library(mxnet)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘mxnet’:
.onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'mxnet', details:
call: inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...)
error: unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.1patched/library/mxnet/libs/x64/libmxnet.dll':
LoadLibrary failure: The specified module could not be found.

I checked the directory. The dll was found.

What is wrong?

Comment: Please check your CUDA version.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I solved the problem. Really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the version of the CUDA. Update to the latest version solves the problem.